# Combobox trigger not working to set selected index

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have a situation where i need to set SelectedIndex of my combobox to 0 in case the selectedItem gets deleted from the ItemsSource collection. A small sample replicates this situation well -

**Xaml**

```
<Grid>
   <ComboBox x:Name="cmb" ItemsSource="{Binding Names}" VerticalAlignment="Top">
     <ComboBox.Style>
       <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
         <Style.Triggers>
             <Trigger Property="SelectedValue" Value="{x:Null}">
                <Setter Property="SelectedIndex" Value="0"/>
             </Trigger>
         </Style.Triggers>
       </Style>
     </ComboBox.Style>
  </ComboBox>
  <Button VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="100" Height="20" Click="Button_Click"/>
</Grid>
```

I haven't binded my SelectedItem or SelectedIndex to any value. On load, trigger works fine and set the SelectedIndex to 0 but on button click, i am deleting the current selectedItem from Names collection. Hence, the selected value is set to null. But the trigger not fires in that case and combobox comes as blank.

I know it can be solved in code behind by listening to `SelectionChanged` event and setting the SelectedIndex back to 0 there in case currentItem is null. But, i can't use that approach because of some restrictions. I want some pure xaml approach. Thanks in advance..

**EDIT**

Setting `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem` to `True` for combobox, prevents combobox to be empty but on removing the selectedItem from ItemSource collection, it set the next available value to be selected but i want my first item to be selected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's because you can't have the same value inside the trigger as what the trigger is based on, and essentially `SelectedValue`, 'SelectedItem', and `SelectedIndex` are just different ways to refer to the same item.

You'll note if you add a background color to the trigger, it gets applied, so the trigger is definitely working.

I'm not sure what restrictions you have which you say are preventing you from using `SelectionChanged`, however I often see people say stuff like that because they are new to the MVVM design pattern, and think it means an application should have no code-behind at all. That is incorrect.

Using MVVM means that there should be no business logic in the code-behind. UI logic is perfectly acceptable in the code-behind a View, and I would consider this to be UI logic because the only thing it is doing is altering the UI based on a UI value.

Comment: You are right. But since i have binded a SelectionChanged command with my ViewModel command using Interaction triggers. Hence, hooking Selection Changed event in code behind won't trigger that command. And invoking that commmand from code behind seems not a good idea. Your thoughts on this?

Comment: @RV1987 Hrrm my thoughts are you should not be hooking up the `SelectionChanged` event to a ViewModel command. If you want to trigger something in the ViewModel when the selection changes, you should do so in the `PropertyChanged` event of the CurrentItem in your ViewModel. For example, if your ViewModel has an `ObservableCollection<MyItem> Items` and `MyItem CurrentItem`, then you should run your logic for selection changing when `CurrentItem` changes, in the `PropertyChanged` event. This keeps UI logic and Business logic separate.

Comment: Yeah, that's how it should go. But since my binding of SelectedItem is OneWay(binded to readonly property) as it binds directly to business layer object. That's why i used SelectionChanged event and wrote my logic over there.

Comment: @RV1987 Why is your binding one-way? Doesn't that mean you have to manually provide a way to update the selected item in your ViewModel when the selection changes? SelectedItem should always be two-way because how can you change it if it is only one-way? Even if you were forced to use a read-only property, couldn't you expose another public read/write property that returns the read-only property on get, and execute whatever code is needed to update it on set?

Comment: Marking this as answer for your effort. :) Thanks, i know using the property here is best approach but some constraints were there which were refraining me to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are anyway deleting the selected item in the button_Click, Could you not accomplish what you want by setting the selectedIndex value to zero inside the Button_Click(sender, eventargs) handler after you delete the current selected item!

Comment: As i said, that's just a simple sample to repro my condition. Otheriwse, xaml is bit complex where i am not using Button_Click event to remove an item.